# com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate cannot be cast to java.security.Certificate

Tags: android, ssl, certificate

> ```
>         CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
>         AssetManager assetManager = MyApp.getAppContext().getAssets();
>         InputStream caInput = assetManager.open("cert.pem");
>         Certificate ca = null;
>         try {
>             ca = (Certificate) cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
>             System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
>         } catch(Exception er)
>         {
>             System.out.println("ssdad222a "+er.getMessage());
>         }finally {
>             caInput.close();
>         }
>         String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
>         KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
>         keyStore.load(null, null);
>         keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", (java.security.cert.Certificate) ca);
>         String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
>         TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
>         tmf.init(keyStore);
>         SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
>         context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);       
>         return context;
> ```

SO I get 09-10 22:18:35.329: I/System.out(18269): ssdad222a com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509Certificate cannot be cast to java.security.Certificate , errors whenever I use cert.pem or cert.der files i got . Whats the error, and solution?

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it appears that you're importing the deprecated java.security.Certificate class. This should be changed to java.security.cert.Certificate. However, you may cast directly to X509Certificate since you're requesting an instance of an "X.509" CertificateFactory. It will not return anything other than X509Certificate instances.